# Custom ArrayAdapter in Fragment not calling getView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to load a list of objects inside a ListView, that is contained inside a Fragment. But I can't get it to work no matter what.

I've tried to load the same data and the same list directly inside the main activity and it works. But not in the fragment.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity** - The fragment loads correctly, data from the server is retrieved, everything is ok here.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.side_menu);

        if (SharedPreferencesManager.isAuthenticated(getApplicationContext())) {
            ServerComm.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).requestMenuItems(new BaseVolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMenuRequest(Menu result) {
                    leftSideMenu = (SideMenuFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.left_side_menu);
                    leftSideMenu.menuItemList = result.top;
                    leftSideMenu.test();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

**Fragment**: Again, everything looks to be fine

```
public class SideMenuFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItemList;
    View mView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.side_menu, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mView = view;
    }

    public void test(){
        MenuItemAdapter adapter = new MenuItemAdapter(getContext(), menuItemList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final MenuItem item = (MenuItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            activity.loadContent(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Adapter**: - Constructor called with the list of items, getCount() is called with the correct number of items. getView - NOT CALLED.

```
class MenuItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<MenuItem> menuList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MenuItemAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<MenuItem> list) {
        super(context, 0 , list);
        mContext = context;
        menuList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return menuList.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.menu_cell, parent, false);
        }
        MenuItem item = menuList.get(position);

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        tvName.setText(item.name);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.dbl.SideMenuFragment"
        android:id="@+id/left_side_menu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

**side_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**menu_cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Honestly, I don't know what I could try next.

Comment: You haven't call `test()` function anywhere in `Fragment`

Comment: @KishoreJethava he's calling from `mainactivity` .

Comment: what about context()?  try adding `getActivity().getApplicationContext()' in adapter initialisation

Comment: Can you also post your xml layouts please

Comment: Looks like the problem might be with your R.layout.side_menu or R.layout.menu_cell. Sometimes there is no space to render the list. Try to match_parent in fragment container and in the list.

Comment: Added the layouts...